# Legend not displaying color

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have drawn a plot in `R`.

```
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1), xlab=expression(delta),ylab="K", xaxs="i",yaxs="i",main = "Zones of extreme equality and inequality in BO1") # Empty plot
cols <- c("red","black")
legend("topright",legend=c("Gini < 0.05","Gini > 0.6"), density=c(NA,NA), angle=c(NA,NA), col=cols)
```

The box in the legend is not getting coloured. What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `pch`:

```
legend("topright",
       legend=c("Gini < 0.05","Gini > 0.6"), 
       pch=15,
       col=cols)
```

Comment: PhilGoetz, [`?par` will reveal the magic behind `pch=15`.](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can also just put the colors in fill:

```
legend("topright",legend=c("Gini < 0.05","Gini > 0.6"), fill=cols)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you try it like this:

```
legend("topright",legend=c("Gini < 0.05","Gini > 0.6"), pch=15, col=cols)
```